# Java- method which returns generic type needs @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") and (T) new Result()

Tags: java, android, generics

I use this methods to get fragment,

```
abstract <T extends Fragment & IMyItem> T createFragment();

public <T extends Fragment & IMyItem> T getFragment() {
    return createFragment();
}
```

and

```
@Override
<T extends Fragment & IMyItem> T createFragment() {
    return new MyPageFragmentImpl();
}
```

on eclispe, this method says

Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyPageFragmentImpl to T

But MyPageFragmentImpl's definition is

```
public final class MyPageFramgmentImpl extends Fragment implements IMyItem
```

I think any class which

```
extends Fragment implements IMyItem
```

MUST be ok for

```
<T extends Fragment & IMyItem>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think any class which "extends Fragment implements IMyItem" MUST be ok

Any such classes are a valid substitute for the type parameter `T`, that is where the problem is. Now suppose you have another class:

```
class AnotherFragment extends Fragment implements IMyItem { }
```

And then you call that method like:

```
AnotherFragment anotherFragment = createFragment();
```

This invocation would pass at compile time. But suppose it compiler allowed you to return `new MyPageFragmentImpl();` from your method, the assignment would fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`, as a `MyPageFragmentImpl` is not an `AnotherFragment`.

You must return a result of type `T` from that method, and the type parameter `T` will be inferred from the type of reference you are assigning the result to. So, the point is, how would you create an instance of `T`? You can't directly do that. One possibility is to pass a `Class` instance to that method, and change the signature to:

```
@Override
<T extends Fragment & IMyItem> T createFragment(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Now, whatever instance you want that method to return, just pass a `Class` instance for that class to this method, like so:

```
MyPageFragmentImpl pageFragment = createFragment(MyPageFragmentImpl.class);
```

In this case, the type parameter `T` will be inferred as `MyPageFragmentImpl`, and the assignment like above would be safe now.

This might fail if your class doesn't have a 0-arg constructor. For that, you can get the appropriate constructor for the class using [`Class#getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method, and then return the instance using [`Constructor#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Comment: But as that's in enum, I can't put class per onClick. I think I need to create a new MyItemFragment.